# How to Convert Attribute Centric XML to Element Centric So I can Import to Access/Excel?

Tags: xml, xslt

OK, so I am working in an e-Commerce platform that exports data in attribute centric XML. I need to convert it into Element Centric XML so I can then convert it into some sort of data table format for easy readability by other teams in my organization.  I found a potential answer in an older thread here (see below), but being that my experience with XML is limited to using it for Soap UI testing, I have no idea how to use the solution so maybe some people here can either explain it, or chime in with other ideas of how to accomplish what I need to do.

The XML I'm using sort of resembles this, but is much longer with more levels to it.

```
  <ns2:order id="">
  <ns2:order-header>
     <ns2:order-process-info>
        <ns2:status></ns2:status>
        <ns2:creation-date></ns2:creation-date>
     </ns2:order-process-info>
     <order-info>
        <document-no></document-no>
        <store></store>
        <locale></locale>
        <currency></currency>
        <calculation-rule-set></calculation-rule-set>
        <order-reference-id></order-reference-id>
     </order-info>
     <ns2:customer>
        <ns2:customer-id></ns2:customer-id>
        <ns2:customer-type-id></ns2:customer-type-id>
        <ns2:calculation-type></ns2:calculation-type>
        <ns2:first-name></ns2:first-name>
        <ns2:last-name></ns2:last-name>
        <ns2:company-name1></ns2:company-name1>
        <ns2:department />
        <ns2:taxationid />
        <ns2:user-id />
     </ns2:customer>
```

I then found this XSLT, but my question is how do I use it? What information from the XML needs to go into the XSLT, and where do I run it from? I've tried finding this answer on my own, to no avail.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL   /Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/@*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[1]">
<Note1><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[2]">
<Note2><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[3]">
<Note3><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[4]">
<Note4><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note4>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[5]">
<Note5><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note5>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You realize that the input XML you've shown only has a single attribute in it, right -- hardly *attribute centric*.

Comment: See if this nice generic solution by Jim Garrison doesn't help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340272/convert-all-nodes-attributes-into-child-nodes

Comment: I only added part of it.

Comment: I'd say to add a real [mcve], but really, Jim Garrison's XSLT should suffice to answer your question.  Is there a reason we shouldn't close this question as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: OK, I see Garrison's solution, but like I said even about the one I found above. I don't know how to use it. What information from my XML do I put into it? Where do I run it? I'm sorry if this is lame, but I am totally out of my depth here.

Comment: There is a reason, because all he posted was a clip of code with no explanation on it's usage or where to run it?

Comment: Colleagues, he is asking how to run the XSLT, that's all...

Comment: I won't say it's "lame," but running basic XSLT is something you should learn about via introductory books and tutorials, really, not asking here.  Closing as duplicate...

Comment: ouch, i think its ok to ask here

Comment: I get that, but when a project is given to you, it's not exactly time for a reference book, and when I search for how to do something threads like Garrison's show up. Not tutorials.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928129/apply-xslt-on-xml-before-importing-into-excel

Comment: and for msaccess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835619/importing-xml-into-access-with-an-xsl-transform    or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829650/xslt-to-change-xml-in-ms-access-import

Comment: This helped a lot.